# How can I use C# code in html?

Tags: asp.net, html

I'm using this code in my html:

```
<a href="<%# ((bool)Eval("IsLinkToOther")) ? Eval("NewsLink") : ../News.aspx?NewsId=Eval("NewsId") %>"><%# Eval("Title") %></a>
```

or this:

```
<a <%if(((bool)Eval("IsLinkToOther")))
   { %>
     href="<%#Eval("NewsLink")%>"                               
<% } %>
 <%else
   {%>
     href="../News.aspx?NewsId=<%#Eval("NewsId")%>"
<% } %> ><%# Eval("Title") %></a>
```

But It's not working, how I use them, please help, thanks...

Comment: Define not working. Are you loading the code from a server which supports ASP.net?

Comment: What is it supposed to do? What does it actually does?

Comment: I don't like to judge, but that's some nasty code.

Answer (score 1):

Pure HTML is rendered and interpreted on the client. C# is normally used on the server side (in aspx files for example).

So to have that running, you must serve it from a ASP.NET capable server such as IIS with ASP.NET enabled.

If you're looking for client side functionality, you should go with Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding

```
runat="server"
```

attribute to your HTML tags?

Answer (score 0):

With all due respect, don't do this **unless absolutely necessary**. It's a really bad habit to mix presentation layer with code-behind.

The correct way, in my opinion, would be to utilize the fact you're using asp.net.

Page.aspx

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="myLink" NavigateUrl="" runat="server" />
```

Page.aspx.cs

```
myLink.NavigateUrl = SomeClass.IsLinkToOther ? SomeClass.NewsLink : "~/News.aspx?NewsId=" + SomeClass.NewsId;
```

Comment: Everything there looks like presentation to me. Ugly, badly done... but presentation. For instance, Eval() is a bata binding method.

Comment: @AndrewBarber, he's including curly brackets and logic (if, else...) as well... THAT'S my biggest complain. Does it seem like a good practice to you? Can you immediately see, what's going on? This has nothing to do with clean code, nor with separation of layers.

Comment: I already said it's ugly and badly done. But it *is* presentation code. *Yes*, he's doing it **all** wrong... but not in the way you are complaining about. There's no reason you can't have ifs and curly braces for presnetation... but yes, again; he's **not** doing it right.

Comment: This should be a comment **not** an answer

Comment: @AndrewBarber, I dare to disagree. Presentation layer, in my opinion, shouldn't contain any deciding logic inside at all. He's clearly deciding which URL to use for href depending on some variable. But I'm glad that we can at least agree on the matter, that this is just wrong the way he presented it :)

Comment: @Rob, fine, updating the answer......

Comment: Nevermind me. I'm too busy :)